# Inherit Constructors and add additionally

Tags: c++, inheritance, constructor

I Have one Saver class (derived from QObject) and one, which is derived from this Saver class (Creator). In the Saver class I defined some constructors which I want to use when I initialize the Creator class. But also I have additional constructors in the Creator class. I use:

```
Saver::Saver
```

in the Creator class to inherit the constructors and it works well, unless I add additional constructors.
Here are the Headers of the classes:

```
class Saver : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    explicit Saver();
    explicit Saver(QVector<QOpenGLVertexArrayObject *> vaos);
    explicit Saver(QVector<QOpenGLTexture *> textures);
};


class Creator : public Saver
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    using Saver::Saver;
    //Works well unless I add the following two lines
    Creator(QVector<Creator *> creators);
    Creator(Creator *creator);
};
```

Do I need to redefine all the constructors (there are many more than in this example) or is there any other solution?

Comment: What happens after you add those two lines? In what way does it cease to work well? Show a [mcve], and the complete text of any error messages.

Comment: [XY answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem): If it is not possible to have a `Saver` that is not a saver of multiple things, eg both `QOpenGLVertexArrayObject *` and `QOpenGLTexture *`, you should consider making `Saver` a template and save on having vast numbers of different constructors.

Comment: Without seeing the error messages from your compiler, I would guess that use of `explicit` in the base class constructors is the culprit. Try removing them.

Comment: What c++ standard and compiler version do you use, if I am not mistaking, inheriting constructors were not available before c++11

Comment: @user4581301 my question wasn't how to implement the Saver class, rather than why the constructors are not inherited when i add additional constructors and how to avoid this in future.

Comment: Understood. My point is it's likely you can avoid the problem completely with a different path.

Comment: @user4581301 I hadn't understood, I will try to implement your solution, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that duplicates the problem.

```
struct type_a {};
struct type_b {};

class Saver
{
   public:
      explicit Saver() {}
      explicit Saver(type_a) {}
};


class Creator : public Saver
{
   public:
      using Saver::Saver;
      Creator(type_b) {}
};

int main()
{
   Creator c1;
   Creator c2(type_a{});
   Creator c3(type_b{});
};
```

One way to solve the problem is to remove the `explicit` qualifier from the default constructor of the base class and add a default implementaton of the default constructor in the derived class.

```
struct type_a {};
struct type_b {};

class Saver
{
   public:
      Saver() {}
      explicit Saver(type_a) {}
};


class Creator : public Saver
{
   public:
      using Saver::Saver;
      Creator() = default;
      Creator(type_b) {}
};

int main()
{
   Creator c1;
   Creator c2(type_a{});
   Creator c3(type_b{});
};
```

Another way to resolve the problem would be to use the default constructor of the base class explicit in the initializer list. You still need to add a default implementation of the default constructor in the derived class.

```
struct type_a {};
struct type_b {};

class Saver
{
   public:
      explicit Saver() {}
      explicit Saver(type_a) {}
};


class Creator : public Saver
{
   public:
      using Saver::Saver;
      Creator() = default;
      Creator(type_b) : Saver() {}
};

int main()
{
   Creator c1;
   Creator c2(type_a{});
   Creator c3(type_b{});
};
```

Comment: Fixed the problem. What causes this problem?